# Split string after one character or another

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that contains many lines such as these:

```
2011-03-23  10:11:08    34  57  2   25,5    -
2011-03-23  10:11:12    67  54  3   3,5 -
2011-03-23  10:11:16    76  57  3   2,4 -
2011-03-23  10:11:18    39  41  2   25,5    +
```

Each line ends with `+` or `-`. I'd like the file content to be split after `+` or `-` sign. Lines doesn't have same number of characters.

I was trying to read the file using `fgets()` with `auto_detect_line_endings` on, but there were still many lines combined into single one:

**Output example**:
Output should be two lines but there is only one (you can see the "the new line" but PHP doesn't):

`2011-03-23 10:11:08    34  57  2   25,5    -
2011-03-23  10:11:12    67  54  3   3,5 -`

**EDIT**:

Code I am using to read the file

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $index = 1;
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if (trim($line) != '') {
                $data = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
                // Saving into DB...
                $index++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: if this is your exact output, why don't you split by `\n`

Comment: Could you post the code you are using right now?

Comment: @Royal Bg, it's an input :) But I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: @PeterO. wheter it's input or not, if the user press the new line button (enter) it becomes `\n` or `\n\n` in windows

Comment: I have tried to use `\n` and `\r\n`. The result is the same as the one using `fgets()`.

Comment: use explode instead of *_split and check what your array has, there should be 4 elements instead of 2, I cannot understand why do you recieve less elements, maybe you are overwriting something.

Comment: I've used `explode("\r\n", $fileContent)`. Neither do I undestand. IMHO there is problem with line ending. So file content should be split after last character in line, `+` or `-`.

Comment: Once you split it by `\n` you can remove the last character

Comment: Try out `preg_split('/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)/', $input)` to hit all the [possible combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: @h2ooooooo, Thank you very much, all possible combinations work. Please, add it as a answer and I'll mark it as correct...Thank you everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you get all of the possible [new line combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) you should use `preg_split` instead:

> `LF` = `\n`, `CR` = `\r`
>
> `LF`:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (GNU/Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS and others.
>   `CR`:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9
>   `LF+CR`: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.
>   `CR+LF`: Microsoft Windows, DEC TOPS-10, RT-11 and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes, CP/M, MP/M, DOS (MS-DOS, PC DOS, etc.), Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS, Amstrad CPC

The regex would be `/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)/` (`CR+LF` or `LF+CR` or `LF` or `CR`):

```
$lines = preg_split('/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)/', $string);
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/hH2fE1)

---

If you plan on not having any empty lines (lines with white space count as empty) you can add an optional `\s*` to the end of your regex which will match 0 to an infinite amount of white spaces after your newlines:

```
$lines = preg_split('/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)\s*/', $string);
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/bS4nF4)

---

If you plan on not having any empty lines, but expect lines with white space to *not* count as empty, you can even simplify the regex:

```
$lines = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $string);
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rE2wG6)

Comment: Actually, you can use `\R` instead of `(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)`.

Comment: @Jerry That's news to me - super cool! Why is this documented absolutely nowhere under [regex escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) except for in the comments? It seems to be in the [PCRE documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5cR), though.

Comment: @Jerry [Even more weird is that it works fine in PHP `4.4.6` - `4.4.9` and `5.2.2+`, but not in `4.3.0` - `4.4.5` and `5.0.0` - `5.2.1`](http://3v4l.org/StB33). My guess is that they fixed the bug at the same time (while they were still developing both PHP4 and PHP5 with bugfixes)

Comment: Ehh, I don't know PHP, but I know that it's on regex101's Quick Reference under 'Meta sequences' > 'Unicode lines \R' ^^

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:**

```
<?php
  $input = "2011-03-23  10:11:08    34  57  2   25,5    -
          2011-03-23  10:11:12    67  54  3   3,5 -
          2011-03-23  10:11:16    76  57  3   2,4 -
          2011-03-23  10:11:18    39  41  2   25,5    +";

  // 1st explode by new line
  $output = explode("\n", $input);
  print_r($output);


  // 2nd remove last character
  $result = array();
  foreach($output as $op)
  {
     $result[] = substr($op, 0, -1);
  }
  print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
   [0] => 2011-03-23  10:11:08    34  57  2   25,5    -
   [1] => 2011-03-23  10:11:12    67  54  3   3,5 -
   [2] => 2011-03-23  10:11:16    76  57  3   2,4 -
   [3] => 2011-03-23  10:11:18    39  41  2   25,5    +
)
Array
(
   [0] => 2011-03-23  10:11:08    34  57  2   25,5    
   [1] => 2011-03-23  10:11:12    67  54  3   3,5 
   [2] => 2011-03-23  10:11:16    76  57  3   2,4 
   [3] => 2011-03-23  10:11:18    39  41  2   25,5    
)
```

**DEMO:** 
http://3v4l.org/0uIe7#v430

Comment: It might be better to use references or array_map, and, ofcourse, nor substring but rtrim